# Dart/Flutter - yield from callback function

Tags: redux, flutter, dart, bloc

I need to make a function call which does not return anything (`void`). Only way to get notified about function completion is sending a `callback` function.
Now I an using `BLoC` pattern along with `ReDux`, When an event is dispatched, I dispatch another action to store of `redux`, After `action` is completed it calls the `callback` function. And now inside `callback` function, I want to update the `state` of `bloc`. Below is my implementation,

```
if (event is Login) {
  yield currentState.copyWith(formProcessing: true);
  store.dispatch(authActions.login(
    currentState.username,
    currentState.password,
    (error, data) {
      print(error);
      print(data);
      // I want to yield here.
      yield currentState.copyWith(formProcessing: false);
    },
  ));
}
```

As shown in the above code snippet, Inside the callback function, I want to `yield`.

## Solution

Create a function that returns the future and makes callback function to store dispatch, Heres sample.

```
if (event is Login) {
  yield currentState.copyWith(formProcessing: true);

  try {
    dynamic result = await loginAction(store, currentState.username, currentState.password);
    print(result);
    yield currentState.copyWith(formProcessing: false);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

Future loginAction(store, username, password) {
  var completer = new Completer();

  store.dispatch(authActions.login(
    username,
    password,
    (error, data) {
      if (error != null) {
        completer.completeError(error);
      } else if (data != null) {
        completer.complete(data);
      }
    },
  ));

  return completer.future;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create other `event`, and `dispatch` this `event` in your `callback` function, then you can do what you want in the function that filter your `events`.

I don't know what is the purpose of your BLoC, but the name of this `event` depends on the use case,  it can be `UpdateForm`, `UpdateState`, `LoggedIn`,`LoggedOut`, etc.  You will find the most descriptive name for your use case.

Remember that you can also create this `event` with parameters, for example `UpdateForm (bool isLoggedIn)`, and `yield` different `states` according to your conditions.

For the example, the name of this `event` is `OtherEvent`.

```dart
if (event is Login) {
  yield currentState.copyWith(formProcessing: true);
  store.dispatch(authActions.login(
    currentState.username,
    currentState.password,
    (error, data) {
      print(error);
      print(data);

      dispatch(OtherEvent());
    },
  ));
} else if (event is OtherEvent) {
   // You can yield here what you want
   yield currentState.copyWith(formProcessing: false);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, I solved it by wrapping my store.dispatch function which returns me a Future, And awaiting that future I'm able to yield after that.

Comment: In flutter_bloc v1.0.0 or later you should use `add()` method instead of `dispatch()` method.